# Android get connection to sql server

Tags: android

I need to connect to local sql server, but when run code below,

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.3.2:8080/app", "test", "1234");
```

the logcat display warning message:

```
06-10 01:24:22.112    2676-2676/com.example.androidapp.helloandroid W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I dont know what does the warning message means?? I have tried to googled and they recommend use `localhost/127.0.0.1/10.0.2.2/10.0.3.2/(local ip address) or remove port number`, but it isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

you can not use localHost there should be client server communication. Between a device and server.

So use an ip address remove localHost from url and **if you are able to ping that ip from another machine then only we can access it from your android device**.

Comment: ok. will try later. But may I know what does the warning message means?

Comment: `So use an ip address` ? He already tried three. You forgot to tell which ip address. `if you are able to ping that ip from another machine then only we can access it from your android device.`. No that is not needed. If you want to use ping then try to ping the server from the device.